# How to configure jul-to-slf4j without programatically

Tags: java, slf4j, java.util.logging, jul-to-slf4j

I'm using slf4j and log4j2 combination as logging framework in my application. To redirect logs of java.util.logging into slf4j, I'm using jul-to-slf4j. I also have to execute :

```
static {
        LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
        SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
    }
```

the above to register the handler to make this work and it is working fine. But I would like to avoid this static block if it possible to do the same handler register by using log4j2.xml file configuration. I spent much time to find the xml configuration but could not found it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not running the code in a servlet container like Tomcat you can simply add the `-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager` to the launch command.

Otherwise should be able to use a [logging.properties](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-jul/index.html) file with contents:

```
handlers=org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.Log4jBridgeHandler.propagateLevels = true
```

Then launch the application with [`-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html).  You'll have to adjust the path to the logging.properties